# Can i backup Ubuntu Windows Installation?

Tags: backup

I have Ubuntu-11.10-desktop-i386.iso and wanted to install  it within Windows. I found out the Ubuntu recognized my wireless device without even installing any drivers, which i didn't see in Linux Mint 15, so i plan to install this Ubuntu-11.10-desktop-i386 within Windows and update it quickly and make a backup of this Ubuntu.
Is it possible to do so? since this will be installed within Windows.
Any suggestions are welcome.

Comment: Please try 12.04 (supported until Apr 2017) or 13.04 (supported until Apr 2014). [11.10 is not supported since May 2013](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases), therefore you won't get support from the official channels if you install it (and may have problems installing software from the repositories).

Comment: And, please avoid Wubi (= installation "inside" windows). It is discouraged and has lots of problems. Please do the dual boot installation unless you have a very good reason not to

Answer (score 0):

The Ubuntu installation is stored on a virtual disk on the windows file system. From the windows point of view the virtual disk containing the Linux install is just another file. So the easiest way is probably to make a backup from the windows side. Locate the file and copy it to a external medium. It probably resides in the folder C:\Ubuntu\disks.

You might want to have a look at this URL: 
[https://wiki.ubuntu.com/WubiGuide](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/WubiGuide#How_can_I_make_a_backup_of_my_Wubi_install.3F)

Comment: I am currently downloading ubuntu 13 as sosytee suggested and follow up with what Hinz said, if the entire Ubuntu Windows Installation resided just another file, then i would probably do that. Copy that file residing in C:\Ubuntu\disks.  Thank you all you have been a great help, please keep suggesting queries, it might help to not start another topic. Thank you. :)